# Подсветка синтаксиса в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

День добрый.
Странный вопрос. У меня недавно, а может и всегда так было - я раньше не замечал, при вводе строковых значений стала выделяться цветом последняя буква. Как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это только у меня так? Как бы убрать? (бесит невероятно)

Comment: Может быть вы `Insert` или `0-Ins` нажали? Могу ошибаться, но это явно была нажата какая либо комбинация - можно еще попробовать `CTRL+D` снять выделение. Так сложно конечно судить, вообще в таких моментах, нужно запоминать, что нажимаете - если ничего не помогает, попробуйте переустановить.

Comment: дело не в нажатом инсерте конечно